# Ember route namespace?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make a namespace within Ember routes and I'm not sure how to do it. I have a resource which should have nested resources when it is in an edit mode. For example:

```
/category
/category/edit
/category/edit/subcategory
/category/edit/subcategory/new
```

But when I try to do

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('category', function() {
    this.resource('edit', {path: '/edit'}, function() {
      this.resource('subcategory', function() {
        this.route('edit');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I get this:

```
category.index
edit.index
subcategory.edit
subcategory.index
```

But what I really want is something like:

```
  category.index
  categoryEdit.index
  subcategory.edit
  subcategory.index
```

Or maybe even:

```
  category.index
  categoryEdit.index
  categoryEdit.subcategory.edit
  categoryEdit.subcategory.index
```

What would be the proper way to setup this type of route?

For a little more information subcategory is a modal, so I want the category view (behind it) to be in the `edit` state if the user was to refresh the url on that page.